# How do I specify a data source alias in a tJDBCConnection in Talend 5.4.1

Tags: connection, pool, talend

I am trying to specify a data source alias within a `tJDBCConnection` component in talend. I have made a file called `datasource.xml` which specifies my connection pool parameters but when I try to deploy and run it I get a

```
<service_name> is waiting for dependencies
[(&(osgi.jndi.service.name=datasource.xml...
```

Does anybody know how I correctly tell talend where to find my file? Under the specify data source alias box I typed the alias as datasource.xml

thank you very much,

Jason